# Frame doesn't disappear

Tags: java

I have two classes, `Class1` and `Class2`, each extending Frame.

I create an object of type `Class2` right before the `dispose()` command in Class1.

How come the `Class2` frame doesn't disappear along with the `Class1` frame after the `dispose()` command?

Comment: Why should it??

Comment: Is this using an AWT based `Frame`, a Swing based `JFrame`..? For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You've instantiated a new frame. You'll need to dispose of that frame when you are done with it in order for it to disappear. Class1 will not dispose of Class2 unless Class1 tells Class2 to dispose itself. Class2 knows nothing about Class1.

Comment: I was thinking that the object of type Class2 would be destroyed on dispose.

Comment: @calind If I eat two apples and put one of the apple cores in the trash, does that imply that the other apple core is in the trash? They're two distinct objects, so I'm not sure what is making you think they're related.